# How to create VPN client app in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

I was surfing the net but still have not found any info of how to make a VPN client app or how to establish connection using React Native.
I found that there is a library in Flutter but I still hope that there is a solution in React Native.

Comment: This question was already asked. The URL to the page is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61773794/how-to-make-an-vpn-app-using-react-native