# How to make an vpn app using react native

Tags: react-native, vpn, pptp, l2tp

I Searched a lot about how to make an **l2tp** or **pptp** **vpn** app using **react-native**
but i didn't find anything
anyone has solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Example projects:

[react-native-vpn-app](https://github.com/S-PRO/react-native-vpn-app)

[react-native-vpn-app forks](https://github.com/S-PRO/react-native-vpn-app/network/members)

[vpn-app](https://github.com/react-ui-kit/dribbble2react/tree/master/vpn-app)

You can fork them on github and make the changes you want to.

[EDIT]

You can use [react-native-ip-sec-vpn](https://github.com/sijav/react-native-ip-sec-vpn) now!

Use it like as follow:

```
import {prepare, connect} from "react-native-ip-sec-vpn";
...
useEffect(() => {
    prepare();
}); /// or use componentDidmount in case of a class component
...
connect(address, username, password)
```

Comment: all of the mention  apps are just UI. the package no shown is depricated

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq Some of them might not be working as intended too, as now the react-native framework became more up to date and those projects use an old version of react-native. 2 years of difference should make those projects break with new stuff!

Comment: the mentioned project  has just ui and are not real vpn apps